# advice testing rails application controllers in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am unsure how to write a test for an application controller.

Using a before filter, I have a method that delivers content to each controller page. I am not looking for someone to write out the test spec for me, just some guidance on how to write it. I dont want to write this test into every sub class controller.

```
before_action :deliver_cms_content, except: [:centre_locator, :top_facilities]

  def deliver_cms_content
    pull_panels
    pull_mpus
  end

  def pull_page_data
    model_page_scope = ("#{params[:action]}_page").to_sym
    if CorporatePage.respond_to?(model_page_scope) and CorporatePage.send(model_page_scope).any?
      CorporatePage.send(model_page_scope).live.last
    end
  end 

  def pull_panels
    page_data = pull_page_data
    if page_data
      @section_one = page_data.live_corporate_panels_section_one
      @section_two = page_data.live_corporate_panels_section_two
    end
  end

  def pull_mpus
    page_data = pull_page_data 
    if page_data
      @mpus = page_data.mpus
    end
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: You could create a test / dummy controller that inherits from `ApplicationController` and test that one. This would ensure that `before_action` adds the required methods.

Comment: how? can you provide an example?